# rfc2307bis and posix groups

Tags: ldap, openldap, groups

I've needed to configure LDAP authentication for Joomla! and the only way to get it to work together (with LDAP group based  was by using groupOfUniqueNames, not the posixGroup. In other words, Joomla expects LDAP to follow the RFC2307bis schema.

This beg the question: do other LDAP using applications understand the RFC2307bis schema?

From what I could find, the 4 most important applications do:

- `pam_ldap` and `nss_ldap`
- Samba
- Gosa
- phpLDAPAdmin

Besides that, what is the state of general support for this schema (Apache auth, squid, groupware suites, freeradius)?

Any problems with such configuration (rfc2307bis, pam_ldap, nss_ldap and samba)?

Comment: And there are several revisions of the RFC2307bis schema — [draft 02](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-howard-rfc2307bis-02) was changed to use `groupOfMembers` class with the optional `member` attribute for groups, while the older [draft 01](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-howard-rfc2307bis-01) used `groupOfUniqueNames`, where the `uniqueMember` attribute is mandatory (therefore creating an empty group is not possible without hacks; draft 02 finally fixes this problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what GOsa² developers said, they are using modified RFC2307 schema that not only uses `groupOfUniqueNames` as @SergeyVlasov noted is standard in second draft, but also duplicate the regular NIS schema giving full backwards compatibility (as long as one doesn't use other administrative tools for changing group membership or user creation).

I haven't tried it yet, but it looks like one can use this modified schema without problems.